# How can I serve the Faster RCNN with Resnet 101 model with tensorflow serving

Tags: object-detection, tensorflow-serving

I am trying to serve the Faster RCNN with Resnet 101 model with tensorflow serving.

I know I need to use tf.saved_model.builder.SavedModelBuilder to export the model definition as well as variables, then I need a script like inception_client.py provided by tensorflow_serving.

while I am going through the examples and documentation and experimenting, I think someone may have done the same thing. So plase help if you have done the same or know how to get it done. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Tensorflow Object Detection API has its own exporter script that is more sophisticated than the outdated examples found under Tensorflow Serving.

While building Tensorflow Serving, make sure you pull the latest master commit of tensorflow/tensorflow (>r1.2) and tensorflow/models

**Build Tensorflow Serving for GPU**

`bazel build -c opt --config=cuda tensorflow_serving/...`

If you face errors regarding crosstool and nccl, follow the solutions at 
https://github.com/tensorflow/serving/issues/186#issuecomment-251152755
https://github.com/tensorflow/serving/issues/327#issuecomment-305771708

**Usage**

`python tf_models/object_detection/export_inference_graph.py \
--pipeline_config_path=/path/to/ssd_inception_v2.config \
--trained_checkpoint_prefix=/path/to/trained/checkpoint/model.ckpt \
--output_directory /path/to/output/1 \
--export_as_saved_model \
--input_type=image_tensor`

Note that during export all variables are converted into constants and baked into the protobuf binary. Don't be panicked if you don't find any files under saved_model/variables directory

To start the server,

`bazel-bin/tensorflow_serving/model_servers/tensorflow_model_server --port=9000 --model_name=inception_v2 --model_base_path=/path/to/output --enable_batching=true`

As for the client, the examples under Tensorflow Serving work well

Comment: I have written an export script by following the codes in tensorflow serving examples and the object detection api jupyter notebook, But your answer is better option.

Comment: I am trying to write a proper pipeline_config file, do you know how to write it, where can I find an example?

Comment: You can find template pipeline config files for all available object detection models under tensorflow [here](https://github.com/tensorflow/models/tree/master/object_detection/samples/configs)